# Convert alphabetic string into Integer in C#

Tags: c#, int

Is it possible to convert alphabetical string into int in C#? For example

```
string str = "xyz";
int i = Convert.ToInt32(str);
```

I know it throws an error on the second line, but this is what I want to do.

So how can I convert an alphabetical string to integer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the result you expect when converted? I mean the value of "xyz". Should it be Ascii value of each char or what?

Comment: And what is the integer representation of the alphabetical string `xyz`? Is it 8429? Or maybe 967?

Comment: pleae provide some example of the string with expected integer value

Comment: Convert it into what?  What would you want the value of "xyz" to be as an int

Comment: And what would the outcome of this conversion be?

Comment: So... what number do you want xyz to be represented by?

Comment: [`str.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx)?

Comment: Do you expect xyz==44027 (radix 36)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the literal questions that you have asked

`Is it possible to convert alphabetical string into int in C#?`

Simply put... no

`So how can I convert an alphabetical string to integer?`

You cannot. You can simply TryParse to see if it will parse, but unless you calculate as ASCII value from the characters, there is no built in method in c# (or .NET for that matter) that will do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Text.Encoding ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
string str = "xyz";
Byte[] encodedBytes = ascii.GetBytes(str);
foreach (Byte b in encodedBytes)
{
   return b;
}
```

this will return each characters ascii value... its up to you what you want to do with them

Comment: Actually, it will just return the value of the first character (your loop will be terminated after the first return) :-P

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a string contains a valid number using Int32.TryParse (if your questions is about avoiding an exception to be thrown):

```
int parsed;
if (!Int32.TryParse(str, out parsed))
   //Do Something
```